# ruby Sprintf KeyError

Tags: ruby, printf

When I do the following in ruby:

```
template = "/home/%{:user}/%{:name}/%{:environment}/current"
values = {user: "firera", name: "firera_test", environment: "staging"}
template % values
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: key{:user} not found
        from (irb):3:in `%'
        from (irb):3
```

The key is clearly there, why is it saying it can't find it?

Answer (score 2):

you have defined template incorrectly. It should look like:

```
template = "/home/%{user}/%{name}/%{environment}/current"
values = {user: "firera", name: "firera_test", environment: "staging"}
template % values
#=> "/home/firera/firera_test/staging/current"
```

Comment: AH, yes, I see, thanks for pointing it out, didn't notice that it was because I added colon's into the template when they shouldn't be there.